# Writing numbers and strings to a text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text-files

Please excuse the basic question. I have two column vectors of numeric data, and a column of string data [currently a character array] which I want to export to a text file in the following format:

```
Number (1,1)  Number (2,1)  Text (1)
Number (1,2)  Number (2,2)  Text (2)
...           ...           ...
```

Thus far, I can only get the numbers in the correct output formatting with the following code:

```
a1=cell2mat(final(:,3)); %numeric data, variable 1 to save
no=cell2mat(final(:,4));
strings=char(final(:,2)); %text data to save as 3rd column

a2=zeros(numel(a1),1); %temporary variable
for i=1:numel(a2);
   if no(i)~=1;
      a2(i)=no(i); 
   end
end
a3=a1+a2; %numeric data, variable 2 to save

fid = fopen( 'results.txt', 'wt' );
fprintf(fid, '%f  %f\n',[a1 a3]');
fclose(fid);
```

When I try to write out the string data by changing the penultimate line of code above to

```
fprintf(fid, '%f  %f  %s\n',[a1 a3]',strings');
```

I get a very weird output in the text file:

```
205.000000  205.000000  SUB SUB SUB SUB SUB SUB
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: how does your cell matrix `final` look like? maybe you can post a short example.

Comment: @bushmills final is a <1463 by 5> cell array, where the first line reads 'Pulse Artifact' 'R' 205 1 'ECG'

Comment: when I define `final = {'Pulse Artifact' 'R' 205 1 'ECG'};` and run your code snippet from above with `fprintf(fid, '%f  %f  %s\n',[a1 a3]',strings');` I get the following entry in results.txt: `205.000000  205.000000  R`. Is this what you expected? Maybe there is anything wrong with your data cell?

Comment: @bushmills this is problematic as only the first row of the 3rd column of "final" is stored in "strings", i.e. strings='R', not the entirety of the 3rd column. This gives the same result as I described in the initial question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You just have to find the right combination. Try you use the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html).

Comment: @patrik and how exactly would that help with a text file output?

Comment: @RyanTimms Well for the first, you can skip the `fid` and get a console output. This will allow you to set breakpoint at the printout and check how to transpose, split, flip, merge the matrix. In case I missed some possibility you can try these too.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround for this. I used a for loop for each line:

```
a1=cell2mat(final(:,3)); %numeric data, variable 1 to save
no=cell2mat(final(:,4));
a2=zeros(numel(a1),1); %temporary variable
for i=1:numel(a2);
   if no(i)~=1;
      a2(i)=no(i); 
   end
end
a3=a1+a2; %numeric data, variable 2 to save

fid = fopen( 'results.txt', 'wt' );
for i=1:length(no);
    fprintf(fid, '%f  %f  %s\n',a1(i),a3(i),char(final(i,2)));
end
fclose(fid);
```

Which gave me the text file in the desired format. Thanks to those who helped.